# StreamReader Only Reads and Outputs Last Line From MultiLine, Spaced Text File

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I'm trying to read values from a text file and input them into an array from where I can assign them to text boxes. My text file has the first line as a title name (string/char) and all subsequent lines contain numbers:

[image: picture of text]

There are multiple lines and each value is split by a white-space. My current code is:

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim openreader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Try

        While Not openreader.EndOfStream
            Dim currentline As String
            currentline = openreader.ReadLine()
            currentline = currentline.Trim(" "c)
            Dim inputparts() As String = currentline.Split(" "c)
            TextBox1.Text = inputparts(0)
            TextBox2.Text = inputparts(1) 'This gives out of bounds error
            TextBox3.Text = inputparts(2) 'This gives out of bounds error
            TextBox4.Text = inputparts(3) 'This gives out of bounds error
        End While

    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The file could not be read. The original error is: " & Ex.Message)
    End Try
    openreader.Close()
    End If
```

The issue with this is that the array inputparts has an out of bounds error for anything higher than inputparts(0) and inputparts(0), which is the only element recorded, is always the very last number of the last line. I did not want to define the dimensions of inputparts() since I was my input file to have the freedom to have a range of different values.

Why is the array not recording any values other than the final one - is it because my currentline ends up being the last line - and how can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If any line has no spaces to split on then you get the exception

Comment: Agree with @Steve, this is quite confusing: " My text file has the first line as a title name (string/char) and all subsequent lines contain numbers. There are multiple lines and each value is split by a white-space." Please describe the structure of file or put part of it here.

Comment: And in any case, you have only four textboxes. If have more than one line then you rewrite the textboxes with the content of the current line until you reach the last line. Perhaps you need to call _AppendText_ to the textboxes instead of setting the Text property (replacing whatever was there from the previous loop)

Comment: @Steve I tried running the code with a text file where the firstline has multiple words, with white-spaces in between and now it is recording every word on the first line but nothing from subsequent lines.

Comment: @MikeMakarov Sorry about that! I've added a link to the screenshot to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Probably you should add to your question an example of the input file with at least two lines.

Comment: @Steve I've added the reference which links to an example of the input file. Just to follow-up on your first suggestion, could you clarify a bit more about how would the AppendText help with ensuring that my textboxes aren't being overwritten with every line? Thank you for your help!

Comment: _TextBox1.AppendText(inputparts(0))_ and so on.

Comment: @Steve AppendText would add to my existing textboxes, whereas I want to distribute the different numbers in different textboxes.

Comment: @arya1021 I notice that the text which you gave us a picture of (please add text as text, not as a picture, in future) has a header, a line of dashes, and a blank line before the data starts, which is not the same as your description of it. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to put the parts which come from the split into textboxes would be to have references to the textboxes in an array and set them from the array of items from the line.

With [`Math.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.7.2) we can be sure that if there are not enough items on the line then we don't try to set the text to something which doesn't exist.

```
Using openreader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim tb = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4}

    Try
        While Not openreader.EndOfStream
            Dim currentline As String
            currentline = openreader.ReadLine()
            currentline = currentline.Trim(" "c)
            Dim inputparts() As String = currentline.Split(" "c)

            For i = 0 To Math.Min(tb.Length, inputparts.Length)
                tb(i).Text = inputparts(i)
            Next

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The file could not be read. The original error is: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Using
```

I used the `Using` statement because it makes sure that the file is closed even if an exception occurs.

If you add `Imports System.IO` at the very top of the code, you don't have to keep typing it in things like `System.IO.StreamReader`.